# How to keep oracle and orientdb database in sync?

Tags: orientdb

I want to keep oracle and orientdb databases in near real time sync and vice versa. Is there any tool/ mechanism to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrientDB had just released a new tool that allows exactly what you want. Its name is Teleporter and you can use it to:

- Import your existing RDBMS to OrientDB.
- Keep your OrientDB database synchronized with changes from the RDBMS.

This tool supports migration and sync with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HSQLDB DBMSs.

Teleported has been released few days ago with the new orientdb 2.2.0-beta version and even though is not yet integrated (it isn't a definitive release) is really easy to insall.
Here is the Teleporter page on orientdb.com:

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-labs/teleporter/

and here you can find the link to the documentation:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-labs/blob/master/Teleporter-Index.md